# Python: If Dictionary key matched in one column replace, another column with value

Tags: python, csv

Simple question here, I have

- a dictionary twodee with waternumbers as keys and residence times as values
- when the waternumber matches the value in column two (line.split()[1]) I want to overwrite the value in column 9 of fileName2 with the value of the dictionary

I've been trying for like a half hour now and it seems a bit basic to post but maybe it will help someone else out in the future.

```
twodee = dict(zip(waternumber, residencetime))


with open(fileName2, "r") as otherinput:
    try:
        for line in otherinput:
            for waternumber, residencetime in twodee.iteritems():
                line.split()[1] == waternumber
                line.split()[9] = residencetime
    except:
        pass
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Shouldn't this read `line=line.split() ; if line[1] == waternumber: line[9]=residencetime; line=" ".join(line)` or something similar?

Comment: you mean `temp=line.split() ; if tmp[1] == waternumber: tmp[9]=residencetime; line=" ".join(line)` but that is not possible. you cant modify the line you are reading. especially when the file is open in read mode

Comment: of course you'd have to write the modified line again somehow -- use use `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning the result of the `.split()` to anything, nor are you testing correctly. Moreover, you don't need to loop over your twodee dict at all, simply test if the `waternumber` value is present in the dict with the `in` operator:

```
for line in otherinput:
    line = line.split()
    waternumber = int(line[1])
    if waternumber in twodee:
        line[9] = twodee[waternumber]
    print line
```

Last but not least, you want to actually do something with the changed line, here I print it.

To elaborate a little, your two lines with `.split()` in them are operations that end up doing nothing:

```
            line.split()[1] == waternumber
            line.split()[9] = residencetime
```

The first operation splits the line to a list, selects the first elements and tests if that is equal to the `waternumber` value. This'll be either `True` or `False`, but you don't do anything with than boolean value. It just is dropped, python doesn't act on it, and the next line is executed regardless.

The second operation again splits the line to a list, selects the 9th element, and replaces that with the value of `residencetime`. But, the result of `line.split()` does not magically change the value of `list`, it *returns* a list, which in this case doesn't get assigned to anything and thus is dropped again.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! This script now returns the lines but unchanged? Could this be to do with the fact it's 'r'. Also it still isn't replacing the 9th value with the residence time? My question was also about the writing out, you can tell I'm a bit of a novice so anything you can add would help.

Comment: if it outputs the lines unchanged, then none of the `line[1]` values ever match keys in your `twodee` dict. Use some `print repr(line[1])` statements (and such) to debug your code.

Comment: so when I print the dictionary I get something like this

...', 199: '10.89'}

and when I print line[1] I get the bare number

Comment: Ah, your keys are integers, but your line is a string. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks very much, this might be the thing

Comment: As to the writing out bit? I've tried some stuff like         
           fileName2.writelines(["%s\n"] % item for item in line) but that's not working, it says fileName2 is now a string and no longer a file, how can I get it to write out within the iterator?

Comment: Better make new posts for new questions and not clutter up the comments.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the appropriate line please? It is in response to the original question which does say overwrite?

Comment: You can't overwrite a file you are currently reading, at least not without some very careful buffering and handling of data size changes. Write to a new file.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions for you code:

1. Don't use try-except when not specyfing more-or-less specific exception (specify only exceptions that you expect to happen). You have errors inside try-except and they are all silently passed.
2. Your replacements won't help you as you don't store results in any meaningful way (you just change some iteration variable that is lost on each next iteration
3. `line.split()[1] == waternumber` is not an assignment, it's a comparison, this line is evaluated as an expression and the result is lost further.
4. The result of .split() is a brand new list object, whose item is changed; this new object is lost in further (see 2).